# MySQL request return null Controller PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I've create a table order on my code, My idea is to generate an Unique order Id per user.

On my controller I have a code with the MYSQL request, and a function to return the result (which works on other SQL requests).

So My idea is on MySQL request is to count the number of order with the same number and If result is =1 I have to generate a new order number. On my order class I have this function:

```
    public static function getCountOrderIfExist($bdd, $order_number) {
    $requete = "SELECT * FROM Order WHERE order_number='$order_number'";
    $commandes = getResultatRequete($bdd, $requete);
    return !empty($commandes) ? $commandes : null;
}
```

And I call it on my Controller:

```
$count = Order::getCountOrderIfExist($bdd, $order_number);
                        while ($count >= 1) {
                            $order_number= $user_role."_".$user->getUtilisateurId().rand(1,99999)."_".$user->getEntreprise()->getId().rand(1,999999);
                        }
```

And here is the code of my `getResultatRequete`:

```
function getResultatsRequete(PDO $bdd, $requete) {
    $reponse_requete = $bdd->query($requete);
    if ($reponse_requete != false) {
        $resultat_requete = $reponse_requete->fetchAll();
        return str_replace("\\", "", $resultat_requete);
    } else {
        printErrorInfo($bdd, $requete, true);
        return array();
    }
}
```

When I run my code on debug mode the SQL request return NULL and I don't understand why, because when I run my Request on a terminal it works well. Any idea?

Comment: What code do you have in `getResultatRequete()`

Comment: You're currently missing a space between "Order" and "WHERE" in your SQL query. That could be your problem, though I would have expected you to see an error instead of a null response if that's the case.

Comment: In your request you wrote "OrderWHERE" missing space maybe ?

Comment: About the space it's just a wrong thing, I've renanmed some var to share the code. My bad.

Comment: the `getResultatRequete` is here : `function getResultatsRequete(PDO $bdd, $requete) {
    $reponse_requete = $bdd->query($requete);
    if ($reponse_requete != false) {
        $resultat_requete = $reponse_requete->fetchAll();
        return str_replace("\\", "", $resultat_requete);
    } else {
        printErrorInfo($bdd, $requete, true);
        return array();
    }
}`

Comment: When you call the function, is $order_number set to something that you know exists in the table? Otherwise it seems perfectly reasonable that it should return NULL.

Comment: I've try to set something that already exist and I have a Null. Why the COUNT should return Null and not 0 ?

Comment: You don't at any point in your code do an actual count. $count will either contain the fetched records or null: `return !empty($commandes) ? $commandes : null;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From our correspondence in the comments, it seems that the problem lies in the return statement:

```
return !empty($commandes) ? $commandes : null;
```

That statement returns any found records, or null if no records are found. However, it seems that the controller expects the function to return the number of matching records (0 if none are found).

In order to return a number for you to work with, you need to instead do a count of the returned records:

```
return count($commandes);
```

This should give you the results you need.

Comment: I've modify my return as you say and also tried to change the request with a `SELECT count(order_number) `but I still have a null as a return.

Comment: Well so I've found my mistake on the request (Like=). But I don't understand <hy count returns "2" when I have only 1 entry

Comment: @NoobieNoob You will need to post your new code if you need help troubleshooting it. It could be that there are two elements in the array that is returned from PDO for some reason, so I would start by dumping that.´